# Having graphs in main page of doxygen

Tags: graph, uml, doxygen, dot

I have used the following code to have a graph in main page of doxygen

```
/*! \mainpage
\dot
 digraph example{
 node[shape=record, fontname=Helvetica, fontsize=10];
 b [label="class cell_deinterleaver"  URL= "\ref Cell_deinterleaver" ];
 c [label="class freq_deinterleaver" URL= "\ref freq_deinterleaver" ];
 b -> c [arrowhead= "open", style = "dashed"];
 }
 \endot
 */
```

But I get the following message "reached end of file while inside a dot block! The command that should end the block seems to be missing!"

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: At first glance looks OK. Which version of doxygen do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is like the message says:

> warning: reached end of file while inside a dot block! The command
>   that should end the block seems to be missing!

it is the mistake that is easily overlooked,  written is
`\endot` this should be `\enddot` (note the double `d`)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any references that include different comments in a dot block to plot more complex diagrams? @albert

Comment: How can I write something beside the arrow? @albert

Comment: Best to have a look that graphviz says about it, don't know about the text but maybe 'label'