# Writing beside arrows in doxygen dot graphs

Tags: graph, uml, doxygen, dot

I want to plot a graph in doxygen. I have used the following code.

```
/*! \mainpage
\dot
digraph example{
    node[shape=record, fontname=Helvetica, fontsize=10];
    b [label="thread_USRP" ];
    c [label="worker1"  ];
    d [label="worker2"  ];
    e [label="threadUDP_Tx"  ];
    b -> c [arrowhead= "open", style = "solid"];
    b -> d [arrowhead= "open", style = "solid"];
    c -> e [arrowhead= "open", style = "solid"];
    d -> e [arrowhead= "open", style = "solid"];
}
\enddot
*/
```

I want to write something beside the arrows. How can I do that? I also want the arrow from node `b` to reach a horizontal line and then from the horizontal line I have two arrows that one goes to node `c` and the other goes to `d` (something like a tree graph). Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comment of [Having graphs in main page of doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913542/having-graphs-in-main-page-of-doxygen) the graphviz site (http://graphviz.org/) has a lot of information. In the gallery (http://graphviz.org/gallery/) will give some nice pictures and in e.g. fsm (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/fsm.html) we see a nice example and also the used code:

```
LR_0 -> LR_2 [ label = "SS(B)" ]
```

So with the `label` attribute